# loading imageviews of collectionview after the viewcontroller is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, uiimageview

So I am building an app in swift where a user can upload a product with pictures. The upload works perfectly but the problem I'm having is the download of the pictures. The user gets an overview of all the products and clicks on them and that sends him to a detailed overview of that product. In that overview, there is a collectionview with all the images (that is the goal). My problem is that the picture are loaded too slow for the collection view and don't appear on the screen. I was wondering if there was an option to give the image view in a function and assign images to them and that the pictures will load one by one after the screen did already load?

This is the function that I am having right now to load my images:

```
    func getPictures(imageStrings: [String], imageViews: [UIImageView]){
        let storage = Storage.storage();
        for index in 0...imageStrings.count - 1 {
            let gsReference = storage.reference(forURL: imageStrings[index])
            gsReference.getData(maxSize: 15 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                            print(error)
                            return
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        imageViews[index].image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        }
                        print(UIImage(data: data!) as Any)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the viewcontroller where my collection view is active

```
import MessageUI
import FirebaseStorage

class ProductDetailViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource   {


    @IBOutlet var TitleLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var PriceLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ProductDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var UsernameLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var LocationLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Userdate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ReserveerButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var DescriptionTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var titleLable = String()
    var priceLable = String()
    var productDate = String()
    var descriptionLable = String()
    var userId = String()
    var usernameLable = String()
    var locationLable = String()
    var userdate = String()
    var email = String()
    var imageStrings = [String]()
    var images = [UIImage]()
    var dbhelper = DBHelper()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ReserveerButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        loadUser(id: userId)
        TitleLable.text = titleLable
        PriceLable.text = priceLable
        ProductDate.text = productDate
        DescriptionTextView.text = descriptionLable
        UsernameLable.text = usernameLable
        loadImages()    

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    private func loadUser(id: String){
        let dbhelper = DBHelper()
        dbhelper.getUserbyUserID(id: id){ success in
            if(dbhelper.users[0].Bedrijf != "NULL"){
                self.UsernameLable.text = dbhelper.users[0].Bedrijf
            } else {
                self.UsernameLable.text = dbhelper.users[0].Voornaam + " " + dbhelper.users[0].Familienaam
            }
            self.Userdate.text = dbhelper.users[0].Added_on
            self.LocationLable.text = dbhelper.users[0].Stad
            self.email = dbhelper.users[0].Email
        }
    }

    @IBAction func ReserveerProduct(_ sender: Any) {
        if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            print("Mail services are not available")
            return
        }

        let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        // Configure the fields of the interface.
        composeVC.setToRecipients([self.email])
        composeVC.setSubject(self.titleLable)
        composeVC.setMessageBody("Beste " + self.usernameLable + ", \n\nIk zou graag het zoekertje " + self.titleLable + " reserveren.  Is dit nog steeds mogelijk? \n\nMet vriendelijke groet" , isHTML: false)

        // Present the view controller modally.
        self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

        switch result.rawValue {
        case MFMailComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue :
            print("Cancelled")

        case MFMailComposeResult.failed.rawValue :
            print("Failed")

        case MFMailComposeResult.saved.rawValue :
            print("Saved")

        case MFMailComposeResult.sent.rawValue :
            print("Sent")
        default: break
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageStrings.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return cell
    }

    func loadImages(){
        let dbhelper = DBHelper()
        //dbhelper.getPictures2(imageStrings: self.imageStrings, imageViews: self.images)
    }

}
```

Hope I can finally solve this problem!
Kind regards
B.

Comment: please elaborate your question more .. I was wondering if there was an option to give the image view in a function and assign images to them.. what does this line means ? Also you need to use some library to get images from server ...

Comment: Hi! Yeah so like in the function ‘getpictures’ in my question above. I get the images from firebase and to get them from firebase I need an imageString but I was wondering if I can assign an image to an imageview from the collectionview in that function?

Comment: why you are fetching all images one time ? they should load once collectionViewCell needs them to load ?

Comment: can you share your collectionView Code ? i can provide you elegant solution for loading images in collectionView

Comment: Thank you! I've added the code.

Comment: from where you call `getPictures` method ?

Comment: Normally It would be in the loadimages function but this is now empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem you are facing is that you do not update your collection view after loading the images.

Firstly, your `getPictures(...)` method expects an array of UIImageViews. But as a matter of fact, you cannot pass them to the method because they are dynamically created in your collectionView. Instead you should return the images, once they are loaded. The problem is that the images are loaded asynchronously. This means that you need to use a completion handler.

```
func getPictures(imageStrings: [String], completionHandler: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
    let storage = Storage.storage();
    for index in 0...imageStrings.count - 1 {
        let gsReference = storage.reference(forURL: imageStrings[index])
        gsReference.getData(maxSize: 15 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                if let error = error {
                        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                        print(error)
                        return
                } else {
                    completionHandler(UIImage(data: data!))
                    print(UIImage(data: data!) as Any)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to modify your `loadImages()` method:

```
    func loadImages() {
        let dbhelper = DBHelper()
        dbhelpergetPictures(imageStrings: [""]) { (loadedImage) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.images.append(loadedImage)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

After that you need to modify your collectionView(numberOfItemsInSection) method in order to make the number of displayed cells equal to the number of loaded images:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}
```

And finally, you need to actually display the images in the UIImageViews inside your collection view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

If you have any questions about this, just ask them in the comments.

(PS: A well-intentioned advice: take a look at the swift naming conventions ([here is a good style guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide)). All names, except from classes, should always start with a lowercase letter and should describe their purpose.
Example: 
`var TitleLable: UILabel!` -> `var titleLable: UILabel!`
and: `var titleLable = String()` -> `var title = String()`
This will make your code way more understandable!)

Comment: Thank you for the advice and all the help. When I try to implement the getpictures method it gives an error "Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completionHandler". Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Yeah. This happened because I forgot something ;) I updated the answer. You just need to add @escaping in front of the parameters.

Comment: Hi, again thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I got an error when filling the imageView of the cell. It gives a 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"  on the ```cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]```line

Comment: This happens because you are trying to access an element of the images-array that does not exist. Try changing your declaration of `var images = [UIImage]()` to `var images: [UIImage] = Array()`

Comment: Did that and still the same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you already change the `numberOfItemsIn' method? Please make sure that it only returns ´images.count´

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213010/discussion-between-adrian1304-and-brecht-verhelst).